# Can a Java annotation spread over multiple lines?

Tags: java, annotations

I use GWT I18N, which relies on annotations for messages with parameters.
Exemple :

```
@DefaultMessage("Here is a message <br/> with a param:{0}")
String messageToLocalize(String param);
```

In absence of a localized translation, the default message will be used.
I have some quite long strings to handle, which I would like to type in sevral lines for code readability (I don't speak about multiple lines for the rendered message).

I tried this :

```
@DefaultMessage("Here is a long \
message <br/> with a \
param:{0}")
String messageToLocalize(String param);
```

It fails (GWT PlugIn 4.2 and SDK 2.5.1) with an error "Invalid Escape Sequence".

Did I miss something ?
Is it a constraint on Java annotations or GWT ? (I am afraid so but couldn't find anything on that)
Is there a workaround ?
Thanks

---

Edit : Given first answers, the question must be rephrased : is it possible, and **which character should I use to show continuation** (if any) ?
The annotation processor obviously needs something to tell him.
I tried "\" because it is the char to use in property file ...
"+" does not work either.

Comment: @kaysush what are you talking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java doesn't support C-style string-lines representation, so you could not use such multi-line style neither in annotations declarations, neither in other places of code.

If you want multiply lines of single string, you have to do something like this:

```
@DefaultMessage("Here is a long " +
        "message <br/> with a " +
        "param:{0}")
```

Comment: Actually I tried "\" because: a) "\" is the character used for property file (property typed on multiple lines), and b): char "+" does not work. I will update my question to make it more clear. thanks anyway.

Comment: @gerard how it could be that `+` doesn't work? It is Java standard string concatenation operator. It seems, that you just missed something when copied my example...

Comment: thanks but I can only confirm that "+" does not work either.  I assume it is a question for annotation preprocessor, and has nothing to do with java copiler.

Comment: @gerard what errors rises when you use `+` symbol? Furthermore, did you mentioned, that you need to split your string by several strings, using `"` quote? If you just will replace symbol `\` (as in your question) with `+` - of course, this will not work

Comment: At last, I am back after a long time...  I tried and you are right : splitting the text not only with `+` (as I did) but having each line in `double-quotes` and concatenating with `+` is fine. Thanks, I will use that.  Still, it is a pity that just having several lines like in JAVA till an end of statement (= end of annotation) wouldn't work (for my need).

Answer (score 1):

As Andremoniy said, it must be cut using Java-style.

But otherwise, I recommend you to have a look at i18nCreator. It allows you to manage your i18n in properties files and have these Messages interfaces files automatically generated:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools#i18nCreator

(There is also a maven plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/i18n.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multiline text-block to spread a java-annotation over multiple lines.
(start and end with three double-quotes)

Like this:

```
@SomeAnnotation("""
This is
a multiline
string
""")
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-multiline-string#text-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try string concatenation that is done at compile time, so:

```
@DefaultMessage("Here is a long"+
"message <br/> with a " +
"param:{0}"")
```

Comment: I tried that also, thanks. (compile time is too late. It is a matter for the annotation preprocessor).